# Elastic Search issue in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am facing below error in exception.log file. How can i resolve this error?

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [amxnotif_hide_alert_value]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v226","node":"YsQHRziLSUeMo8kQPmEqbw","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [hide_value]"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [amxnotif_hide_alert_value]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [hide_value]"}}},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"no mapping found for field [hide_value]\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v226\",\"node\":\"YsQHRziLSUeMo8kQPmEqbw\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"no mapping found for field [hide_value]\"}}],\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"no mapping found for field [hide__value]\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"no mapping found for field [amxnotif_hide_alert_value]\"}}},\"status\":400} at /vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:632)"} []
```

and

```
Cannot search on field [upc_code] since it is not indexed
```

Comment: Hello there, I have not the exact solution but I work around to fix this issue. Please check the eav attribute `upc_code` , `amxnotif_hide_alert_value` is searchable or not. I'm pretty sure these attributes are set to be searchable so please select no to is_searchable for these attribute and then run reindex. Let me know your feedback
Thanks

Comment: @Shankar, Thanks for your reply. Let me apply your fix.

Comment: @sanjay do reindex and then check.

Answer (score 0):

I executed this command in the terminal

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```